# Paypal Gateway Error

Tags: php, magento, paypal

We are using Magento

I have got the below error in exception log file :

exception Mage_Core_Exception with message below:

```
PayPal NVP gateway errors: The transaction cannot complete successfully. 
Instruct the customer to use an alternative payment method 
(#10417: Transaction cannot complete). 
Correlation ID: e9aa67915a70f. 
Version: 60.0. in /home/necro/necroproduct.com/app/Mage.php:536
```

Can anybody help me to solve this error?

Comment: Have you googled the error message?

Comment: Yes, Thanks, but nothing found interesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an error code in your log:

> (#10417: Transaction cannot complete).

According to [the documentation](https://cms.paypal.com/ca/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_nvp_errorcodes) this simply means that the customer does not have enough funds on their account (or has no credit card linked) to pay for the item, as stated:

> Account not associated with a usable funding source.

or

> Credit card or Billing Agreement is required to complete payment.

So, unless you are willing to drop a credit card/billing agreement requirement (if you currently do so at all, that is) there is not much you can do on your end.

Comment: This is fine now. thanks. in Magento, Another issue is I am getting emails from client that they are sometimes getting above messages when they return from paypal. And so they are assuming like their transaction has not completed so they are trying again and again. So I am getting 4 to 5 orders from same client. So can you help in this please!